# Replace two double quotes with single one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

How do I replace two double quotes into single one using jQuery?

For example: I need to replace

> Sam is at his ""Home""

to

> Sam is at his "Home"

Looking for something similar to this regex (which replaces double quotes to single quotes):

```
mystring.replace(/"/g, "'")
```

Comment: In addition, note that this has nothing to do with jQuery, that's vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/""/g, '"');
```

The regex captures two double quotes and replaces them with one. We're using a regex to replace more than a single match (JavaScript's replace will only replace the first one).

Note that the second argument to replace is a string. To represent `"` in a string we need to escape it: `"\""`, or use a single quote string: `'"'`. JavaScript supports both.